# Jasmine + AngularJS: Global services causes Unexpected GET request

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, mocking, jasmine, angular-translate

I have a service, `$language`, that gets called in app config (so before every Spec runs). The method called, `$language.update()`, triggers `$translate.use()` (which in turn triggers an `$http.get()`). This causes an `Unexpected request: GET /<lang>/i18n`.

I've tried a few different things to resolve this, but each seems to cause a new problem:

#### Globally mock the `$translate` service

```
// not inside a describe()
beforeEach(function() {
    module(function($provide) {
        $provide.value('$translate', {
            get:         function() { return false; },
            storage:     function() { return false; },
            storageKey:  function() {
                return {
                    get: function() { return false; },
                    set: function() { return false; }
                };
            },
            use:         function() { return false; }
        });
    });
});
```

But something tries to call `$translate()`, so I tried making the mock a function returning an object, but that didn't work either.

#### Mocking the GET request via $httpBackend

```
// not inside a describe()
beforeEach(function() {
     // this already existed to avoid another problem caused by $translate
    module('MyApp', function config($translateProvider, $anotherProvider) {
        // …
    });

    // new
    inject(function($httpBackend) {
        $httpBackend.when('GET', '/<lang>/i18n').respond({});
    });
});
```

But then it complains `Injector already created, can not register a module!` (order of *module* and *inject* doesn't seem to matter).

I thought of globally mocking my $language service, but then I would not be able to test it in its own Spec.

Ideally I'd prefer to globally mock $translate as it seems to cause one problem after another.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that `$translate` is a provider; therefore a provider needs to be $provide'd:

```
// Outside of a describe so it's treated as global
beforeEach(function() {
    module('MyModule', function config($providerA, $provide) {
        // …
        $provide.provider('$translate', function() {
            var store                 = {};
            this.get                  = function() { return false; };
            this.preferredLanguage    = function() { return false; };
            this.storage              = function() { return false; };
            this.translations         = function() { return {}; };

            this.$get = ['$q', function($q) {
                var $translate        = function(key) {
                    var deferred = $q.defer(); deferred.resolve(key); return deferred.promise;
                };

                $translate.addPair    = function(key, val) { store[key] = val; };
                $translate.isPostCompilingEnabled = function() { return false; };
                $translate.preferredLanguage = function() { return false; };
                $translate.storage    = function() { return false; };
                $translate.storageKey = function() { return true; };
                $translate.use        = function() { return false; };

                return $translate;
            }];
        });
    });
});
```